# View data tables odf database in external device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, device, adb

The only way to get and visualize the data table of my database inside external devices is by atribution of privilege of superuser privilege in external device? Don't exist another way that allow visualize the data tables as in emulator?

I make this question because this way of superuser privilege not inspire me security.

Thanks for your attention (PS: Sorry by mistakes, but english is not my mother language :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add functionality to export the database file from the internal read-only app storage to the SD-Card by simply letting your app copy the file.

Then use whatever ways you have to get it from there. Works on any device and no root required.

```
private void exportDb() {
    File database = getDatabasePath("myDb.db");
    File sdCard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myDb.db");
    if (copy(database, sdCard)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Get db from " + sdCard.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Copying the db failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private static boolean copy(File src, File target) {
    // try creating necessary directories
    target.mkdirs();
    boolean success = false;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(target);
        in = new FileInputStream(src);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // maybe log
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // maybe log
    } finally {
        close(in);
        close(out);
    }
    if (!success) {
        // try to delete failed attempts
        target.delete();
    }
    return success;
}

private static void close(final Closeable closeMe) {
    if (closeMe != null)
        try {
            closeMe.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // ignored
        }
}
```